# Visual Studio - correct python indentation

Tags: python, ptvs

I am working in source files in Python that are half written in spaces and half tabs for indentation. It is infuriating. Is there some tool to automatically fix this?

Comment: Search and replace? (Ctrl+Shift+H in Visual Studio IIRC)

Comment: notepad++ replace in all opened documents, and with extended you can replace `\t` to `    `